# What does the Cable Number field represents in an USB-MIDI Event packet?

Tags: usb, midi

My OS is Windows 7, i use MIDI-OX as a MIDI utility and wireshark as a sniffer.

Currently developping some MIDI app on STM32, i have a hard time understanding the meaning of cable number in an USB-MIDI Event packet.   [USB MIDI Event packet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmnes.png)

The [USB MIDI specification](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/midi10.pdf) states (p.16, 4) that :

> The Cable Number (CN) is a value ranging from 0x0 to 0xF indicating the number assignment of the Embedded MIDI Jack associated with the endpoint that is transferring the data.

In my project, i have an embedded Jack OUT which ID is 3. When trying to send USB-Midi event with a cable Number set at 3, my MIDI messages were not recognized by my MIDI-OX, although they were seen by Wireshark. Changing the cable number to 0 made the MIDI events recognized by MIDI OX. 
But i want to understand why it made it work.

I think i have confused number assignement and Jack ID, so what is this number assignment ?

Comment: I guess I am walking the path you walked. I wish you could help me with figuring out how how to send control transfer request for Class-Specific MS Bulk Data Endpoint Descriptor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 3.1 of the USB MIDI specification says:

> Each Entity within the USB-MIDI function is assigned a unique identification number, the EntityID, contained in the `bJackID` or `bElementID` field of the descriptor. The value 0x00 is reserved for undefined ID, effectively restricting the total number of addressable Entities in the USB-MIDI function (both Jacks and Elements) to 255.

So this cannot be used for a four-bit cable number.

That "number assignment" refers to the following algorithm (which everybody pretends is obvious): the cable numbers of an endpoint are from zero to one less than `bNumEmbMIDIJack`.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I managed to have several MIDI out recognized and working with it. This cable number is the Index of the Jack as indicated in the Class-Specific MS Bulk Data Endpoint Descriptor.

Comment: @Buta9az, I guess I am walking the path you walked. I wish you could help me with figuring out how how to send control transfer request for Class-Specific MS Bulk Data Endpoint Descriptor

Comment: @CL. do you mean the cable number for a jack is its 0 based index in the endpoint descriptor? so the jack with jackID that is the first "baAssocJackID" in the endpoint descriptor should have cable 0, next one cable 1 and so on? I was trying to understand if I should use jackID as cable number

Comment: @Hasan Cable numbers must be between 0 and 15, but jack IDs can have values up to 255. And yes, the jacks associated with an endpoint are those indicated by `baAssocJackID`.

Comment: thanks a lot, the cable related stuff is really cryptic (or I am not able to understand it), I was trying to reverse engineer it by reading descriptors and trying different stuff. Thanks for confirmation, this is really helpful!